# Javascript if statement SyntaxError:syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax-error

I have the following code :

```
var _compteur = '.$compteur.';
var _init = 0;

$("#scrolldown").click(
  if (_init>0) {
        $("#video").animate({marginTop: "+=95px"}, 200);
        _init-=1;
        _compteur+=1;
  }
  else {}
);

$("#scrollup").click(
  if (_compteur>3) {
        $("#video").animate({marginTop: "-=95px"}, 200);
        _init+=1;
        _compteur-=1;
  }
  else {}
);
```

$compteur is a php variable wich I pass to my JS, firebug return the error SyntaxError:syntax error (with no other detail) for my if statement : if (_init>0) {

I don't understand where's the error, maybe it's confusing with the Jquery, but I can't get this to work.

thx for the help :)

Comment: I would open the debugger and see what each if statement returns. For example, set a breakpoint on your if statement and then paste `_init>0` in there and see if you get a true/false return or if you get the syntax error.

Comment: You need a function within the click handler. Ex: `$("#scrolldown").click(function(){...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
$("#scrolldown").click(function() {
  if (_init>0) {
        $("#video").animate({marginTop: "+=95px"}, 200);
        _init-=1;
        _compteur+=1;
  }
  else {}
});
```

and

```
$("#scrollup").click(function() {
  if (_compteur>3) {
        $("#video").animate({marginTop: "-=95px"}, 200);
        _init-=1;
        _compteur+=1;
  }
  else {}
});
```

in fact this is the correct way to attach the event handlers.

Comment: this works, i already used .click event until now, don't know why I forgot  the function keyword now

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) feel free to upvote and/or accept my answer if it solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

You don't attach an event handler like this, you are missing the function keyword
Try

```
$("#scrolldown").click(function() {
    $("#video").animate({marginTop: "+=95px"}, 200);
    _init-=1;
    _compteur+=1;
});
```

Also, check the examples here: http://api.jquery.com/click/